# remove the delete button ⛔️ on table rows in edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to learn Swift, but there is a problem in my project that drives me nuts.
I have a working list of data in a ViewController fed by parse.com. I managed to implement a swipe-feature that reveals buttons for both deleting and editing. That is working fine. Now I want the user to be able to reorder the cells. So I successfully implemented a button to put the table into editing-mode. My 2 problems with that are:

1. When I enter edit-mode I just want to be able to reorder the cells since editing and deleting is done via swipe (via "tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)". How can I achive that the user doesn't see the 2 buttons for deleting and editing when in editing-mode and touching the delete-circle that is provided automatically?
2. Is it possible to remove the delete-circle altogether? Using "UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None" also disables the swipe-functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Implement the `canEditRowAtIndexPath` data source method and return `false` if the table is in editing mode and `true` if it isn't

Comment: Unfortunately that keeps the swipe-action but makes the edit-button do nothing. Code used:

        `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
            if(tableView.editing == true) {
                return false} else {
                return true
            }
        }`

Answer (score 9):

To avoid the round red delete button that appears when you put set UITableView isEditing to true at the left and does nothing when you click it, the minimum that worked for me was this (Swift 4, iOS 11)

// Avoid the round red delete button on the left of the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
```

I also have these functions, which probably interact:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return savedTempTable.isEditing
}

// Including this function in the delegate enable left-swipe deleting
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        savedConversions.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }
}


// Including this function enables reordering
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let elem = savedConversions.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    savedConversions.insert(elem, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: I have found out since that putting these lines in stops the swipe-left gesture from revealing the delete button.

Answer (score 3):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although people can delete a row through swipe the delete-button in editing mode should not be removed. People may not know about the swipe gesture and by removing the delete button (which they already expect in editing mode) the app becomes more difficult to use.

If you really want to remove the delete button then you have to implement the delegate method `tableView(_:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:)`. There you can return `.None` while the screen is in editing mode and `.Delete` while the screen is not.

To enable reordering you have to implement the data source methods `tableView(_:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:)` and `tableView(_:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:)`.

Comment: Actually that sounds reasonable.

Comment: OK, so how do you use that delete button? It does nothing by default, even though I would have expected it to call tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) with editingStyle == .delete

Answer (score 1):

You follow this way to remove the delete Icon while editing:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
 }
```